# GeoTools errors and warnings reading .tif file

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, geotools

I'm trying to read my .tiff image using GeoTools. After reading I intend to perform georeferencing of the image using the four coordinates of the image. Following is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FactoryException {
        AbstractGridCoverage2DReader data = new GeoTiffReader(new FileInputStream(new File("a.tif")));
        GridCoverageFactory gcf = new GridCoverageFactory();
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.decode("EPSG:29901");// null;//null;

        int llx = 500000;
        int lly = 105000;
        int urx = 501000;
        int ury = 106000;

        ReferencedEnvelope referencedEnvelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(llx, urx, lly, ury, crs);
        GridCoverage2D gc = gcf.create("name", (RenderedImage) data, referencedEnvelope);
        String url = "random.tif";
        File file = new File(url);
        GeoTiffWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new GeoTiffWriter(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.write(gc, null);
        writer.dispose();
    }
```

I am getting the following exceptions and warnings.

```
WARNING: Coordinate Reference System is not available
Exception in thread "main" org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: null
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:279)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:192)
    at IrishGridConverter.main(IrishGridConverter.java:26)
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: null
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.getHRInfo(GeoTiffReader.java:539)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:265)
    ... 2 more
```

what could be the potential reasons, and how can I solve?

Comment: What is the value of `crs`? do you have a referencing jar in your classpath?

Comment: I have `gt-epsg-hsql` dependency set in my pom.xml.

Comment: is `a.tif` a GeoTiff or just a tiff?

Comment: I'm reading a .tif. I have the coordinate values with respect to the four corners of the image. I want to transform this .tif to a GeoTiff image.

Comment: @IanTurton, I have following jars in my class path, 'gt-epsg-hsql', 'gt-geotiff', 'gt-swing'. do I require to have additional jars?

Comment: Also, what could be the reason to get following error: "Raster to Model Transformation is not available for"

Comment: I don't think you can read in a basic tif file with the geotiff reader as it is expecting to find referencing information in there.  Try `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);` instead

Comment: OK, what could be the reason for the warning `Coordinate Reference System is not available` ? Do I require to have additional jars?

Comment: No I don't think so, you are simply reading in a file with no referencing information in it

Comment: @IanTurton, many thanks, I was able to do my task with BufferedImage. Apparently, I CAN use GeoTool's CoordinateReferenceSystem interface to GeoReference my TiFF image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by trying to read in a "normal" tiff file with no spatial data in it. GeoTools is trying to find the required parts of a GeoTiff and not finding them.

You should read in your tiff using `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputFile);` and you can then create a coverage using `GridCoverage2D gc = gcf.create("name", image, referencedEnvelope);`