# GeoServer Exception (Status Code 500) when creating a CoverageStore through geoserver-rest python library

Tags: python, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, geoserver-rest-py

I'm trying to upload a leyer to GeoServer using [geoserver-rest python library](https://geoserver-rest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to_use.html#creating-coveragestores). I'm using the `CoverageStore` method to create a `Store` on the `Workspace` and subsequently create the `Layer`. This is the code I have to make this happen:

```
geo = Geoserver('http://IP.ADDRESS.OF.SERVER:8080/geoserver', username='username', password='password')
geo.create_coveragestore(layer_name='test_layer1', path=r'C:\Users\username\Downloads\test_layer1.tiff', workspace='test_workspace')
```

Connection to GeoServer is successful, but I'm getting the following error on the second line of code:

```
geo.Geoserver.GeoserverException: Status : 500 - b'Could not acquire reader for coverage.'
```

When I check the GUI of GeoServer I see that a `Store` was created in the provided `Workspace`, but the `Layer` was not created. The **Connection Paramaters URL** is set to **"file:data/test_workspace/test_layer1/test_layer1.geotiff"** which looks normal.

The TIFF file I'm using is one that I had previously uploaded to GeoServer through the GUI, but I'm trying to have the capability of uploading programmatically through Python.

After enabling `GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING` I'm getting this error with a bit of more information.

```
01 Mar 12:53:12 WARN   [gce.geotiff] - Coordinate Reference System is not available
01 Mar 12:53:12 WARN   [gce.geotiff] - Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: /home/rlab/data_dir/data/test_workspace/test_layer/test_layer.geotiff
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: /home/rlab/data_dir/data/test_workspace/test_layer/test_layer.geotiff
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:288)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:327)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffFormat.getReader(GeoTiffFormat.java:77)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:244)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:190)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: /home/rlab/data_dir/data/test_workspace/test_layer/test_layer.geotiff
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.getHRInfo(GeoTiffReader.java:584)
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.<init>(GeoTiffReader.java:274)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: /home/rlab/data_dir/data/test_workspace/test_layer/test_layer.geotiff
    at org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader.getHRInfo(GeoTiffReader.java:502)
    ... 120 more
01 Mar 12:53:12 ERROR  [geoserver.rest] - Could not acquire reader for coverage.
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Could not acquire reader for coverage.
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:246)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:190)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: What version of geoserver are you using? https://github.com/pvernier/geoserver-api-examples/blob/master/coverage/create-coverage.py might help

Comment: I'm using v2.22.1. Why? @Mapperz

Comment: Well the vulnerability was patched at 2.22.2 for one at https://geoserver.org/vulnerability/2023/02/20/ogc-filter-injection.html and it can help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: So the error I'm getting is because of a vulnerability if I'm understanding correctly? I'll check if updating to 2.22.2 helps. Thanks! @Mapperz

Comment: there is a difference between `test_layer1.tiff` and `test_layer1.geotiff` that is probably significant

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I went to Global Settings -> Logging Settings -> Logging Profile and selected GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING. Still getting the same Exception, nothing else is showing up. @IanTurton

Comment: Also, why would it be uploading it as a ```.geotiff``` when my file is specified to be a ```.tiff``` in the method? @IanTurton

Comment: No idea, check the log and the actual XML being sent to geoserver

Comment: @IanTurton I was able to get a better error log thanks to your comments. I still don't know what's going on, but it's a step forward. I also added the additional error log to the post. Thanks!

Comment: Update: that helped me diagnose the error. Even though GeoTIFF and TIFF files have the same extension of ```.tif```, they don't have the same info so the image I was trying to upload was a TIFF file instead of a GeoTIFF file which is why I was getting the error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling `GEOSERVER_DEVELOPER_LOGGING` in Settings -> Global -> Internal Settings -> Logging Settings -> Logging Profile allowed me to see a log with more information than I was initially getting through the terminal. I made the `POST` request with that setting enabled and I saw the following error:

```
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Raster to Model Transformation is not available for: /home/rlab/data_dir/data/test_workspace/test_layer/test_layer.geotiff
```

I googled the error and stumbled upon [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/396924/219827) on StackExchange. This error is caused by trying to read a "normal" TIFF file with no spatial data in it while GeoServer is trying to find the required parts of a GeoTIFF file and it is not finding them. So to check if this was what was happening to me I went to `Layer Preview` in GeoServer, donwloaded one of the files that I had in GeoTIFF format, and re-tried to make the `POST` request with that new file. It worked! So that was the cause of the error.